# C# How can I read a MultiString from the registry

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm currently reading string keys from the registry. I can pull the values from strings and Expanded strings just fine. But once in a while there is a MultiString that does not return the string. Instead, I see "System.String[]" returning instead of the actual string.

Do I have to convert this multistring to a string somehow? Or is there an easier way to read the actual multistring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on from what you need you should convert it. If you want to store the values as strings, you can convert it using code like this.

```
string sep = ",";
string result = String.Join(sep, stringArr);
```